# Is there a way to get the computer (or hard drive) product name in grub 2.0?

Tags: grub2, grub

I've tried cpuid among other things, but I can't seem to get the computer model. For example, the output I'm looking for would be something like:

```
grub> computermodel
HP Notebook 2016
```

Thanks.

Comment: Here's the complete list of available Grub 2 commands: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access SMBIOS information using the [smbios](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/smbios.html) command.

Example:

```
grub> smbios --type1 --get-string 4  # 0x04 manufacturer 
LENOVO
grub> smbios --type1 --get-string 5  # 0x05 product name 
20HMS12K00
grub> smbios --type1 --get-string 6  # 0x06 version 
ThinkPad X270
grub> smbios --type1 --get-string 25 # 0x19 sku number 
LENOVO_MT_20HM_BU_Think_FM_Thinkpad X270
grub> smbios --type1 --get-string 26 # 0x1A family 
Thinkpad X270
```

Look into the [SMBIOS spec.](https://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios) for a description of all available fields and values. I had a quick look at this [older 3.1.1 spec](https://www.hpe.com/psnow/resources/ebooks/a00114902en_us_v2/SMBIOS_Specification.html) for an overview of the BIOS tables.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! One last thing - do you happen to have a list of all of the valid strings? The link you provided only specified the types.

Comment: Look into the spec where the value is of type string (first or second link). Then you need the structure type and offset to read it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that.